# How can I read and manipulate data from a CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, csv

My code is giving me multiple answers when i use my customer search function and i have no idea why.

We need to use Info from a csv chart.
(I added a picture of it)

Heres my Code:
`

```
import csv
import os
import time
import subprocess

# Standard-Speicherort für Rechnungen (Download-Ordner)
output_folder_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads")

# Pfad zur CSV-Datei im Download-Ordner
csv_file_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/bestellwerte.csv")

# Liste zum Speichern der gelesenen Daten
aggregated_data = []

# Daten aus der CSV-Datei lesen
with open(csv_file_path, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')  # Trennzeichen auf Semikolon setzen
    headers = [header.strip() for header in next(reader)]  # Spaltennamen extrahieren und Leerzeichen entfernen

    #print(headers)

    for row in reader:
        order = {}
        for i, value in enumerate(row):
            order[headers[i]] = value
        aggregated_data.append(order)


# Funktion zum Erstellen der Rechnung
def write_invoice(orders, output_file):
    with open(output_file, 'w') as file:
        file.write("Rechnung\n\n")

        # Extrahiere den Namen und die Order-ID des ersten Auftrags
        customer_name = orders[0]['customername']
        order_id = orders[0]['orderid']

        # Schreibe den Namen und die Order-ID nur einmal in die Rechnung
        file.write("Kunde: {}\n".format(customer_name))
        file.write("Order-ID: {}\n".format(order_id))
        file.write("\n")

        # Schreibe die Details der einzelnen Aufträge in die Rechnung
        file.write("Bestellungen:\n")
        total_price = 0.0
        for order in orders:
            order_detail_id = order['orderdetailid']
            quantity = int(order['quantity'])
            price = float(order['price'])
            subtotal = quantity * price
            total_price += subtotal
            file.write("- Order-Detail-ID: {}\n".format(order_detail_id))
            file.write("  Anzahl: {}\n".format(quantity))
            file.write("  Preis: {}\n".format(price))
            file.write("  Teilsumme: {}\n".format(subtotal))
            file.write("\n")

        # Berechne Steuern und Gesamtpreis
        tax_rate = 0.19  # Steuersatz von 19%
        tax_amount = total_price * tax_rate
        total_price += tax_amount

        file.write("\n")
        file.write("Steuern ({}%): {}\n".format(tax_rate * 100, tax_amount))
        file.write("Gesamtpreis: {}\n".format(total_price))

        print("Die Rechnung für Order-ID {} wurde erfolgreich erstellt.".format(order_id))

    # Rechnung automatisch öffnen
    try:
        subprocess.Popen(['open', output_file])  # Für macOS
    except OSError:
        try:
            subprocess.Popen(['xdg-open', output_file])  # Für Linux
        except OSError:
            try:
                subprocess.Popen(['start', '', output_file], shell=True)  # Für Windows
            except OSError:
                print("Die Rechnung konnte nicht automatisch geöffnet werden.")


# Funktion zum Suchen einer Order-ID
def find_order_by_id(order_id):
    matching_orders = [order for order in aggregated_data if order['orderid'] == order_id]

    if len(matching_orders) == 0:
        print("Die angegebene Order-ID existiert nicht.")
    else:
        print("Folgende Bestellungen wurden gefunden:")
        for order in matching_orders:
            print("- Order-ID: {}, Kunde: {}".format(order['orderid'], order['customername']))
            print("  Order-Detail-ID: {}".format(order['orderdetailid']))
            print("  Anzahl: {}".format(order['quantity']))
            print("  Preis: {}".format(order['price']))
            print("-----------------------------")


# Funktion zum Suchen eines Kunden und Anzeigen der Bestellungen
def find_customer_by_name(customer_name):
    matching_customers = [customer for customer in aggregated_data if customer_name.lower() in customer['customername'].lower()]

    if len(matching_customers) == 0:
        print("Es wurden keine Kunden mit diesem Namen gefunden.")
    else:
        for customer in matching_customers:
            print("Kunde: {}".format(customer['customername']))

            # Bestellungen des aktuellen Kunden sammeln
            customer_orders = [order for order in aggregated_data if order['customername'] == customer['customername']]

            # Set zum Speichern der eindeutigen Order-IDs
            order_ids = set()

            for order in customer_orders:
                order_id = order['orderid']
                if order_id not in order_ids:
                    print("Bestellungen:")
                    order_ids.add(order_id)
                print("- Order-ID: {}".format(order_id))
                print("  Order-Detail-ID: {}".format(order['orderdetailid']))
                print("  Anzahl: {}".format(order['quantity']))
                print("  Preis: {}".format(order['price']))
                print("-----------------------------")

# Funktion zum Ändern des Speicherorts für Rechnungen
def change_output_folder(new_folder_path):
    global output_folder_path
    output_folder_path = new_folder_path


# User-Menü
while True:
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')  # Löscht die Konsolenausgabe

    # Benutzerinformationen anzeigen
    print("User Menu:")

    # Benutzermenü anzeigen
    print("[C]reate invoice, [f]ind OrderId, [S]earch Customer, Speicher[o]rt Festlegen, E[x]it")
    answer = input()

    # Rechnung erstellen
    if answer.lower() == "c":
        order_id_input = input("Geben Sie die Order-ID ein: ")
        matching_orders = [order for order in aggregated_data if order['orderid'] == order_id_input]

        if len(matching_orders) == 0:
            print("Die angegebene Order-ID existiert nicht.")
        else:
            print("Folgende Bestellungen wurden gefunden:")
            for order in matching_orders:
                print("- Order-ID: {}, Kunde: {}".format(order['orderid'], order['customername']))

            output_file = os.path.join(output_folder_path, 'Rechnung {}.txt'.format(order_id_input))
            write_invoice(matching_orders, output_file)

    # Order-ID suchen
    elif answer.lower() == "f":
        order_id_input = input("Geben Sie die Order-ID ein: ")
        find_order_by_id(order_id_input)

    # Kunde suchen
    elif answer.lower() == "s":
        customer_name_input = input("Geben Sie den Namen des Kunden oder einen Teil des Namens ein: ")
        find_customer_by_name(customer_name_input)



    # Speicherort ändern
    elif answer.lower() == "o":
        print("Möchten Sie den Speicherordner ändern? [y/n]")
        question2 = input("")
        if question2 == "y":
            print("Geben Sie den neuen Speicherordner-Pfad an:")
            new_folder_path = input(r"[Beispiel: C:\Users\tim-o\OneDrive\Desktop\Rechnung py] ")
            change_output_folder(new_folder_path)
            print("Speicherort geändert!")

    # Programm beenden
    elif answer.lower() == "x":
        answer = input("Wollen Sie das Menü wirklich beenden? [y/n]").lower()
        if answer == "y":
            print("Das Programm wird nun beendet")
            for i in range(20):
                print(".....", end='')
                time.sleep(0.05)
            break
```

Itd be great if one you yall was able to solve my problem.
(Its in german btw)
I tried it myself and with help from chatgpt and nothing seems to work.

Comment: You'll need to explain just what your specific "problem" is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read all your code, so I cannot tell exactly where a problem might be.  However, I can see that currently I'm having a hard time following the logic and flow.

I'll suggest you make a big structural change: put the big while-True loop in a main function that gets the user input and acts accordingly; then call main inside a try-except to handle the user aborting with a Ctrl-C:

```py
...

def main():
    data = get_data()

    while True:
        choice = get_menu_input()
        match choice:
            case "x":
                if confirm_exit():
                    break
            case "c":
                create_invoice(data)
            case "f":
                pass
            case "o":
                pass
            case "s":
                pass
            case _:
                pass  # unexpected menu choice; show menu again

...

try:
    main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nDas Programm wurde vom Benutzer unterbrochen")
    pass
```

I like this because I can clearly see where the program starts, and that there are only ways to exit: 1) a user-confirmed exit 2) some expection (of which KeyboardInterrupt is expected and handled).

The match-case relies on Python 3.10+, but even if you had a sequence of if-elifs...-else I think that'd still look very clear and approachable.  Functions like get_menu_input(), confirm_exit(), and create_invoice() still have user interaction.  I'd try to keep main very light/clean to start, but you might want to bring all the user inputs up to main (in which case you wouldn't need create_invoice(), you just prompt for the order ID, inside the `case "c":` block, and call write_invoice(...)).

Here's a complete sample which can at least write an invoice and open the text file in TextEdit on my Mac.  I also rewrote the CSV reader to use a DictReader.  I can see that you need to trim the header first.  If you only need to skip leading spaces in the header names, just use the `skipinitialspace=True` option in a DictReader and be done with it.

```py
import csv
import os
import platform
import subprocess

Output_Folder_Path = os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads")
Input_Path = "input.csv"

Data = list[dict[str, str]]


def main():
    data = get_data()

    while True:
        choice = get_menu_input()
        match choice:
            case "x":
                if confirm_exit():
                    break
            case "c":
                create_invoice(data)
            case "f":
                pass
            case "o":
                pass
            case "s":
                pass
            case _:
                pass  # unexpected menu choice; show menu again


def get_data() -> Data:
    with open(Input_Path, "r", newline="") as f:
        # Read just the header, normalize fieldnames
        r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
        header = next(r)
        header = [x.strip() for x in header]

        # The file is still open; the file's "line iterator" is still on line 2...

        # Read w/DictReader for actual data
        r = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=";", fieldnames=header)

        return list(r)


def get_menu_input() -> str:
    # Löscht die Konsolenausgabe
    os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")

    # Benutzermenü anzeigen
    print("User Menu:")
    print("[C]reate invoice, [f]ind OrderId, [S]earch Customer, Speicher[o]rt Festlegen, E[x]it")

    return input().lower().strip()


def confirm_exit() -> bool:
    answer = input("Wollen Sie das Menü wirklich beenden? [y/n] ").lower().strip()
    if answer != "y":
        return False

    print("Das Programm wird nun beendet")
    return True


def create_invoice(data: Data):
    order_id = input("Geben Sie die Order-ID ein: ")
    matching_orders = [order for order in data if order["orderid"] == order_id]

    if len(matching_orders) == 0:
        print("Die angegebene Order-ID existiert nicht.")
        return

    print("Folgende Bestellungen wurden gefunden:")
    for order in matching_orders:
        print("- Order-ID: {}, Kunde: {}".format(order["orderid"], order["customername"]))

    output_file = os.path.join(Output_Folder_Path, "Rechnung {}.txt".format(order_id))
    write_invoice(matching_orders, output_file)


# Funktion zum Erstellen der Rechnung
def write_invoice(orders: Data, output_file: str):
    with open(output_file, "w") as file:
        file.write("Rechnung\n\n")

        # Extrahiere den Namen und die Order-ID des ersten Auftrags
        customer_name = orders[0]["customername"]
        order_id = orders[0]["orderid"]

        # Schreibe den Namen und die Order-ID nur einmal in die Rechnung
        file.write("Kunde: {}\n".format(customer_name))
        file.write("Order-ID: {}\n".format(order_id))
        file.write("\n")

        # Schreibe die Details der einzelnen Aufträge in die Rechnung
        file.write("Bestellungen:\n")
        total_price = 0.0
        for order in orders:
            order_detail_id = order["orderdetailid"]
            quantity = int(order["quantity"])
            price = float(order["price"])
            subtotal = quantity * price
            total_price += subtotal
            file.write("- Order-Detail-ID: {}\n".format(order_detail_id))
            file.write("  Anzahl: {}\n".format(quantity))
            file.write("  Preis: {}\n".format(price))
            file.write("  Teilsumme: {}\n".format(subtotal))
            file.write("\n")

        # Berechne Steuern und Gesamtpreis
        tax_rate = 0.19  # Steuersatz von 19%
        tax_amount = total_price * tax_rate
        total_price += tax_amount

        file.write("\n")
        file.write("Steuern ({}%): {}\n".format(tax_rate * 100, tax_amount))
        file.write("Gesamtpreis: {}\n".format(total_price))

        print("Die Rechnung für Order-ID {} wurde erfolgreich erstellt.".format(order_id))

    # Rechnung automatisch öffnen
    match platform.system():
        case "Darwin":  # macOS
            subprocess.Popen(["open", output_file])
        case "Linux":
            subprocess.Popen(["xdg-open", output_file])
        case "Windows":
            subprocess.Popen(["start", "", output_file], shell=True)
        case _:
            print("Die Rechnung konnte nicht automatisch geöffnet werden.")


try:
    main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nDas Programm wurde vom Benutzer unterbrochen")
    pass
```